# SMTP authentication required for relay error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, smtp-auth

Our site used to be hosted on a server running Windows Server 2003 and IIS 6; it worked fine in this area. Now we are trying to set it up on a new server running Windows Web Server 2008 R2 and IIS 7. On both the old and the new server we are using SmarterMail as our email software.

I have no problem sending and receiving email from Outlook and Windows Live Mail on my local system. The problem is with sending email from the code-behind on our website. I can send an email from the site to an internal email address that is set up in SmarterMail--in other words, to an address within the domain of our mail server. But when I try to send an email from the site to a Gmail address, I get the following error:

550 Authentication is required for relay

In the code-behind for the ASP.NET page that is sending the email, I have the following VB.NET code:

```
Dim MailObj As New SmtpClient
With MailObj
  .Credentials = New NetworkCredential(MailFromEmailAddress, Password)
  .EnableSsl = False
  .Host = "mail.MyDomain.com" ' our mail server subdomain name, configured in IIS
  .Timeout = 180000
  .UseDefaultCredentials = False
End With

MailObj.Send(OrderMailMsg)
```

I can log in to SmarterMail with the MailFromEmailAddress and Password without any problems.

Also, I can define an SMTP Authentication Bypass for the IP address of the mail server, and then the email to the Gmail address goes through fine. But I cannot get the SMTP authentication to work when sending to an address outside our domain from our site.

Does anyone have an idea of what I should change or do to make this work? Thanks very much!

Comment: Check if you have SSL enabled on your email server. Did you try sending an email to an external address by logging in with this mail user credentials? Maybe it does not have permissions.

Comment: Logging in to the mail server through a browser with the Mail From email address, I successfully sent a test email to the Gmail address. I have SSL enabled on the mail server, but till now I have EnableSSL set to False and am using port 25 for SMTP. Should I be using port 465 and setting EnableSSL to True?

Comment: I think you should EnableSSL. And is there any specific certificate provided by the SMTP whose mail services you are using?

Comment: I have an SSL certificate installed in IIS that is specific to the mail subdomain that I'm using. I'll try to get it to work with EnableSSL.

Comment: I'm new to this forum and I don't see how to mark this question as answered.

Comment: That would be because nobody has provided an answer to this question.  All of these have been comments.  If you found your own answer, you should provide it and mark it as the accepted answer (see the text box below).